# Conversion of Sine to Cosine

Tags: trigonometry, conversion

I'm solving equations with many Cosines and Sines.
And I want to convert all the Sines to Cosines using trigonometric formulas such as cos(x)=sin(x+pi/2).
How can I do this?

Comment: Why you need it? Solve commands in mathematica isn't sensitive to such things. And Mathematica automatically treats sin(x+pi/2) as cos(x) unless you force unevaluated form by Hold[sin(x+pi/2)].

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: @funnypony 
Thank you. I need it because I am comparing equations solved by hand and by Mathematica. The solutions by hand are all Cosine based, but Mathematica automatically convert some Cosines to Sines. I expected there could be a function in Mathematica that converts all Sines to Cosines. I think that "Hold" can't be used in my case because I want to convert the Sines after the evaluation of the equations.

Comment: It makes pattern detection a lot easier if you can control the form of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that Mathematica immediately converts terms such as `Sin[x+π/2]` to the more simpler `Cos[x]`. You have to prevent this from occurring. You could do that with `Defer` or in V10 with `Inactivate`:

```
Inactivate[ 
    Cos[p x + 2] Sin[z a + q] + Cos[x]^2/(Sin[a + b] - Cos[2 n]) /. Cos[x_] :> Sin[x + π/2], 
    Sin
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or, perhaps better (per comment of Bob Hanlon):

```
Cos[p*x + 2]*Sin[z*a + q] + Cos[x]^2/(Sin[a + b] - Cos[2*n]) /. Cos[x_] :> Inactive[Sin][x + Pi/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(note that the inactive sines are printed in a gray style).

Comment: Or you can use `Cos[p*x + 2]*Sin[z*a + q] + Cos[x]^2/(Sin[a + b] - Cos[2*n]) /. Cos[x_] :> Inactive[Sin][x + Pi/2]` which leaves the original `Sin` functions active.

Comment: @BobHanlon That may be better indeed if the OP wants to do something with them (though I don't have a clue what that might be)

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for your answer. Your code doesn't work in my PC since I'm using V9. And I don't understand the syntax. Maybe I need more study in Mathematica.

Comment: With v9 you cannot use Inactive or Inactivate but as mentioned by @Sjoerd you can use `Defer`, i.e., `expr = Cos[p*x + 2]*Sin[z*a + q] + Cos[x]^2/(Sin[a + b] - Cos[2*n]) /. Cos[x_] :> Defer[Sin][x + Pi/2]`. To release the `Defer` you can use `expr /. Defer -> Identity`